# Ubuntu 22.04 netns with veth connected to bridge unable to ping gateway

Tags: networking, vpn, ethernet, network-bridge, systemd-networkd

Hey guys this is probably just something stupid I'm missing, but I'm having trouble setting up a net namespace to use for my VPN. The weird part is that this script/setup was working, and has suddenly stopped within the last couple weeks.

I have a single ethernet interface on the server with a static IP set that I want to use for all my normal traffic. I then use a bridge and as its master, and connect the VPN to the same bridge through a virtual ethernet. For some reason my VPN's interface can successfully reply to ARP requests, but doesn't seem to be able to ping my gateway and therefore cannot connect to the internet). I feel like this might be a routing problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**Netplan**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.54/24

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
      - to: 192.168.0.0/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

**Script to Setup VPN Net Namespace:**

```
ip link add vpn0 type veth peer name vpn1

ip link set dev vpn0 master br0

ip netns add vpn

ip link set vpn1 netns vpn

ip link set dev vpn0 promisc on
ip link set vpn0 up

ip netns exec vpn ip link set lo up
ip netns exec vpn ip link set vpn1 up

ip netns exec vpn ip address add 192.168.0.53/24 dev vpn1
ip netns exec vpn ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev vpn1
```

**VPN Address/Routes**

```
root@sam-server:~# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vpn1@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:9e:19:5a:a4:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.53/24 scope global vpn1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::49e:19ff:fe5a:a4a5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@sam-server:~# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev vpn1
192.168.0.0/24 dev vpn1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.53
```

**Normal Address/Routes**

```
root@sam-server:~# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:d7:f6:78:91:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.54/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:3d:5a:ce:a9:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::e43d:5aff:fece:a9fb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:19:80:3c:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vpn0@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 66:2c:f9:35:3d:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns vpn
    inet6 fe80::642c:f9ff:fe35:3d0e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@sam-server:~# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev br0 proto static onlink
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 proto static scope link
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.54
```

**Pinging From VPN Namespae** (Arp seems to resolve, but I can't ping the gateway)

```
root@sam-server:~# ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3066ms

root@sam-server:~# ping 192.168.0.54
PING 192.168.0.54 (192.168.0.54) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.54: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.54: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.54: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.54 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2031ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.037/0.047/0.052/0.007 ms
root@sam-server:~# arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.1              ether   b0:95:75:8c:fe:80   C                     vpn1
192.168.0.54             ether   e6:3d:5a:ce:a9:fb   C                     vpn1
root@sam-server:~#
```

Hopefully this is enough info, I can post more if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my problem. It turned out to be something really simple. Basically, two weeks ago I had installed `Docker`. I wasn't aware of this, but Docker messes with `iptables`.

```
root@sam-server:~# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP) <----------- PROBLEM IS HERE
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Since Docker automatically sets `FORWARD` to `DROP` my packets weren't getting forwarded to the interface. I assume `ARP` was working since it isn't affected by iptables.

The fix was just resetting the policy to accept: `iptables --policy FORWARD ACCCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add macaddress of the interface as suggested here [Ubuntu 22.04 bridging with netplan doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416713/ubuntu-22-04-bridging-with-netplan-doesnt-work)

```
   # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.54/24

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.0.1
      - to: 192.168.0.0/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
      macaddress: 88:d7:f6:78:91:72
```