# Bridged network on Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: network-bridge

I'm trying to set up a couple of VM's with KVM/Qemu. They are supposed to be on the same network as the host. I have tried out a couple of guides found on the internet but to no avail.

Will someone please tell me how to do it?

Best regards

Comment: I have a couple of possible helpful answers, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638162/kvm-network-bridge-to-assign-static-ip/638269#638269) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412503/setting-up-a-bridge-for-host-and-vm/1412973#1412973).

Comment: Both of them are unsuitable for my setup. It's a DHCP situation. No staic IP's.

Comment: O.K. the one I pointed you to for [this same question over on Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2480450) was [for dhcp](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2461631&p=14036896#post14036896)

Comment: Please add important information (like dhcp) to your question above. Volunteers donate their time and effort to help you, so make that donation worthwhile.

Comment: For those coming from the internet to find the right answer. I followed this beautiful article here [Creating an ubuntu kvm networked bridge interface](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/creating-an-ubuntu-kvm-networked-bridge-interface/). It worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

I have done this setup, and it worked before I restarted the host machine. So technically it's correct. [Please try this and see if it works for you](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-setup-bridge-networking-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-20-04-9c560b3e3991).

Essentially it boils down to this:

1. Create a bridge using nm-connection-editor.
2. Join the network interface on the host to the bridge.
3. Remove the existing libvirt network and create a new one using this bridge as basis
4. Select "Virtual network:  bridged network" in the Virtual Machine Manager guest config or use the quivalent cli commands.

The bridge becomes invisible to the guest and host.